# FacebookAppID issue in cordova 2.3

Tags: facebook, cordova

I just implemented Facebook SDK on Cordova 2.3 but you know the most important change looks like in Cordova 2.3 that they changed info.plist to config.xml. On my previous version I had implemented my FacebookAppID in my .plist file but now altough I generated a new config.xml with "bin/cordova_plist_to_config_xml" script and I wrote my appid in my config.xml as a preference name="FacebookAppID" xcode returns me that error:

"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'"

So is there anyone who knows to get over this issue?

Thanks,
Burak

Comment: I'm having the same issue with PhoneGap 2.5. Where are you adding your FB App ID's? According to the instructions, they should be added to [PROJECTNAME]-Info.plist file and should be in the callback for the deviceready event in your Phonegap JS. BTW, I've done this and getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config.xml` only replaces the `Cordova.plist`, not the `<AppName>-Info.plist` where you place the FacebookID.

The `<AppName>-Info.plist` is still there and in use.